# Do Docker Image build from different env results different image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-build

I couldn't understand, why my docker build suddenly not working anymore, it used to be working for both environments. I build using same Dockerfile, locally on my Ubuntu PC and on my Ubuntu Server.

```
ARG GO_VERSION=${GO_VERSION:-latest}
FROM golang:$GO_VERSION

ARG uname=${uname:-gitlab-runner}
ARG uid=${uid:-999}
ARG gid=${gid:-999}

RUN groupadd --gid "$gid" e \
  && useradd --uid "$uid" --gid "$gid" --create-home "$uname"

USER "$uid"

WORKDIR /code
VOLUME /code

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

If I used server builded docker image, the $PATH suddently become

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I lost /go/bin and /usr/local/go/bin paths. However it works if I build it locally on my pc. How could this happened? fyi, the server is an headless ubuntu server. and on my pc, it is ubuntu dekstop.

I also tried to set the env manually.

```
ENV PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

It doesn't help either. I still end up with the default path. I have been looking for answer for months, I could come up with an answer and it is still not working. For now, I build it on my pc manually. Fyi, both run same docker version. I don't think that my environments cause this issue but possibly. maybe someone have idea or solution to fix this issue?

```
Docker: Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b
OS: Linux ******* 5.15.0-87-generic #97-Ubuntu ******* x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And

Docker: Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b
OS: Linux ******* 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC ******* x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Update**:
"Suddenly not working anymore", I don't know how to explain it better. I have a repo which build an docker Image on my Ubuntu Server, it runs for years already without problem. I do occationally update os, update docker for years long without any problem. But, now the builded image not running any command inside these paths.

**what is not working?**
All binaries such as `go`, `gotestsum` whatever exist in `/go/bin` and `/usr/local/go/bin` path, cannot be called anymore. why?
because the path in the container missing `/go/bin` and `/usr/local/go/bin`.

**How do I verified this path?**
I just run the docker image with entrypoint `bash`. Then checked the path variable `$PATH`. it is indeed like what I am telling previously.

**How do I build this Image?**
ntg particular, I only provide the user, uid, gid and the golang version as arguments. The same dockerfile used to build multiple images with different users.
All images build on my desktop environment, works as expected and for all different machines. The Paths contains `/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin`. and all images build on my ubuntu server cannot run those binaries.

The entrypoint should not be the issue. Since I occasionally run go as entrypoint or gotestsum.

My question is, do this issue cause by headless server? and adding new user and group during docker build?
If so, then why `ENV PATH=xxxx` command in dockerfile not work?
With or without this command `ENV PATH=xxxx`, the base docker image from golang should set this path already.
Or maybe this was cause by

```
RUN groupadd --gid "$gid" e \
&& useradd --uid "$uid" --gid "$gid" --create-home "$uname"
```

Then this line should help doesn't it?

```
ENV PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I couldn't reproduce this on my desktop, but only on my server. I build these to match my machines users. why? I don't want to run these image as root and often I encounter Permission Issue, So I build multiple image, so that I can run those Images on my different machines. the build command look like this, really ntg out of ordinary.

```
docker build -t xxxx --build-arg uname=anyname --build-arg uid=1000 --build-arg gid=1000 --build-arg GO_VERSION=1.21-alpine .
```

Comment: Which command are you using to build the image? What does `entrypoint.sh` look like?

Comment: "suddenly not working anymore" is really not a good description. What is the error? What exactly doesn't work? What commands are used to build the images? Please provide a [mcve]!